# Disable swiping in specific Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have a ViewPager with navigation bar in Main Activity.

```
ViewPagerAdapterFragment adapter = new ViewPagerAdapterFragment(getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.AddFragment(new FirstFragment(), "");
    adapter.AddFragment(new SecondFragment(), "");
    adapter.AddFragment(new ThirdFragment(), "");
    fragmentContainer.setAdapter(adapter);
    navigationBar.setupWithViewPager(fragmentContainer);
```

I want to create a FourthFragment that is not defined in ViewPager, can opened in fragmentContainer and can be accessed with a button inside FirstFragment. However when I create this Fragment, I am able to swipe left or right like other ViewPager Fragments. I want to disable this ViewPager swiping in FourthFragment.

I have tried this but it didn't work for me.

```
mDrawer.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED, R.layout.fourthfragment);
```

I would appreciate any hint.

Answer (score 0):

Actually what you would like to do, is break the viewpager concept.
Which you can navigate between the fragments as pages.

Quick idea:

- Don't break viewpager concept.
- Use the same fragment Instance in the pager + you can attach it to another Activity or the same activity you are in it

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about what you want to achieve but it sounds like you want to reach that forth fragment using swiping gesture then when reaching it you want to disable the swipe gesture, which does not make sense.
ViewPager fragments are meant to be swiped.
Why not simply add or replace a newInstance of that fourth fragment out side of the viewPager?